# Execute a cmd file from IIS8

Tags: c#, iis-8

I have a piece of code  which generates excel with some inbuilt functions

```
string xmlfilePath = "C:\\Test\\standard_xml.xml";
string script = "C:\\Test\\script.vbs";
 string template = "Template";
 string cmdfilePath = @"C:\\Test\\executable.cmd";
if (File.Exists(cmdfilePath))
  {
    File.Delete(cmdfilePath);
  }

 using (FileStream fs = File.Create(cmdfilePath))
   {
     Byte[] info = new UTF8Encoding(true).GetBytes("\"" + script + "\"" + " " + 
       "\"" + template + "\"" + " \"" + xmlfilePath + "\"");
     fs.Write(info, 0, info.Length);
   }
     var process = Process.Start(cmdfilePath);
    process.WaitForExit();
```

This codes generates a excel and does some required operations.

This works pretty fine when testing in visual studio, but when i run it on iis8 it never works. I have tried all the various solutions that are mentioned over the web nothing worked.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What exception(s) are you getting? put some logging in to see what lines are executed. Normally this is permission based you could try adding the DefaultAppPool to the directory permissions or check your file is it x64 on a x86 server?

Comment: Hi... it is a x64 server.. unfortunately the log is not helping me much

Comment: Would you be allowed to post the script for the `executable.cmd` file?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing for sure (through some error logs, eventvwr screenshots), my guess is you're running into a permissions issue.

When executing file-based operations from IIS, you need to keep in mind the AppPool Identity that is being used for the website. The AppPool Identity would need to have write permissions to that specific folder.

I would suggest leaving the AppPool user identity to the built-in "ApplicationPoolIdentity", as this is the most secure option.

There is lots of good information on this subject on MSDN: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities

Specifically look at the Securing Resources part for how to add file permissions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#securing-resources

There are other scenarios where you can override the user account for a given AppPool, and even on the website (for things like impersonation, etc), but if you are not doing those, then the above should work.

Comment: Hi ryan.. Thanks for the reply..I tried all this.. but it doesn;t work.. The funny thing i see a process for my cmd in the task manager details. So it is actually creating the process, but just not executing it